# How do I find the dimensions of $r$ and $x$ in order to balance this equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, dimensional-analysis

[image]

The correct equation is $F=\dfrac{Mv^{2}}{r}+x\sqrt{d^{3}t}$.

I know that:

- $F$ has units $N=kg\cdot m\cdot s^{-1}$
- $M$ has units $kg$
- $v$ has units $m\cdot s^{-1}$
- $d$ has units $m$
- $t$ has units $s$

So this is what I tried:

$\Rightarrow kg\cdot m\cdot s^{-1}=kg \cdot m \cdot s^{-1} \cdot r^{-1} + x \cdot \sqrt{m^{3} \cdot s}$

$\Rightarrow kg\cdot m\cdot s^{-1} - kg \cdot m \cdot s^{-1} \cdot r^{-1} = x \cdot \sqrt{m^{3} \cdot s}$

$\Rightarrow (kg\cdot m\cdot s^{-1} - kg \cdot m \cdot s^{-1} \cdot r^{-1})^{2}= x^{2} \cdot m^{3} \cdot s$

$\Rightarrow kg^2 m^2 s^{-2} - 2 kg^2 m^2 s^{-2}r^{-1} + kg^2 m^2 s^{-2}r^{-2} = x^2 m^3 s$

But at this point I don't know how to proceed any further to solve for $r$ or $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force is $N=kg\cdot m\cdot s^{-2}$

Think of weight, mass times acceleration

$W=mg$

$\mathrm {N = kg \cdot m/s^2}$

I also noticed you are trying to algebraically solve for x and r.  This is unnecessary.  You only need to make each additive term have the same units.  In this case, you know each term must have units of force. There is no need for the terms to interact.

Comment: Okay, this is what I tried for the second term of the sum:
$x\sqrt{m^3s} = kgms^{-1}$

$\Rightarrow x^2m^3s=kg^2m^2s^{-2}$

$\Rightarrow x^2=kg^2m^{-1}s^{-3}$

$\Rightarrow x=kgm^{-\frac{1}{2}}s^{-\frac{3}{2}}$

But can the dimensions be fractional like that?

Comment: @AnsarAl Yes, dimensions can be fractional. Not something that you see every day, but nothing forbids it.